# Complex Pandas Dataframe Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D','E'],\
                  'ID2':['B','A','D','C','E'],\
                  'Account':['94000','94500','94000','18300','94500'],\
                  'Amount':[100,-100,50,-50,100],\
                  'Match':['-','-','-','-','-']})
df
```

I am struggling with the most efficient way to identify when an item in 'ID1' is present in 'ID2' with a particular value of Account. For example, with a condition of Account=94500 should yield:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D','E'],\
                  'ID2':['B','A','D','C','E'],\
                  'Account':['94000','94500','94000','18300','94500'],\            'Amount':[100,-100,50,-50,200],'Match':['True','-','-','-','-']})
df
```

i.e. only the first row should be tagged because A (in ID2) matches Account 94500

Comment: it does not work under the slightly modified data set I have posted

Comment: In your updated example E in 94500 and ID2 matches E in ID1, so the last row should be True as well, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation is a bit unclear, but I think you want this:

```
mask = df[df.Account == '94500'].ID2
df.loc[df.ID1.isin(mask),"Match"] = True

  Account  Amount ID1 ID2 Match
0   94000     100   A   B  True
1   94500    -100   B   A     -
2   94000      50   C   D     -
3   18300     -50   D   C     -
4   94500     100   E   E  True
```

Also comparing both correct answers just for fun.

```
%timeit -r 10 df['Match'] = df['ID1'].apply(lambda x: any((df['ID2']==x) & (df['Account']=='94500')))
100 loops, best of 10: 4.21 ms per loop


 %timeit -r 10 df.loc[df.ID1.isin(df[df.Account == '94500'].ID2),"Match"] = True
1000 loops, best of 10: 1.48 ms per loop
```

**Update to address a new use case**

You mentioned that you have problems where there are two columns you want to use. Again I am not sure if I understood it correctly, but here is my take on it. Suppose you have another variable `Prod` and you want to choose both on `Account == 94500` and `Prod == 6901`.

In this case:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D','E'],\
                  'ID2':['B','A','D','C','E'],\
                  'Account':['94000','94500','94000','18300','94500'],\
                  'Amount':[100,-100,50,-50,100],\
                  'Match':['-','-','-','-','-'],\
                  'Prod':[0,6901,0,0,0]
                })

mask = df[(df.Account == '94500') & (df.Prod == 6901)].ID2
df.loc[df.ID1.isin(mask),"Match"] = True
```

Result:

```
  Account  Amount ID1 ID2 Match  Prod
0   94000     100   A   B  True     0
1   94500    -100   B   A     -  6901
2   94000      50   C   D     -     0
3   18300     -50   D   C     -     0
4   94500     100   E   E     -     0
```

Now only 'A' in ID1 matches the condition, since 'A' is in ID2 in 2nd row, so only the first row is selected.

Comment: I stumbled when trying to use your code in a slightly different scenario. If I have another column called 'Prod' and I now want to match based on both account 94500 and Prod 6901, I can't get the code to work !                              

import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D','E'],\
                  'ID2':['B','A','D','C','E'],\
                  'Account':['94000','94500','94000','18300','94500'],\
                  'Prod':['6901','0','0','0','0'],\
                  'Amount':[100,-100,50,-50,100],\
                  'Match':['-','-','-','-','-']})
df

Comment: I stumbled when trying to use your code in a slightly different scenario. If I have another column called 'Prod' and I now want to match based on both account 94500 and Prod 6901, I can't get the code to work !                              
df= pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D','E'],'ID2':['B','A','D','C','E'],'Account':['94000','94500','94000','18300','94500'],'Prod':['6901','0','0','0','0'],'Amount':[100,-100,50,-50,100],'Match':['-','-','-','-','-']}). There should be no matches with a prod of 6901 and a account of 94500

Comment: Changed the condition to address your case if I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['Match'] = df['ID1'].apply(lambda x: any((df['ID2']==x) & (df['Account']=='94500')))
```

Which gives:

```
  Account  Amount ID1 ID2  Match
0   94000     100   A   B   True
1   94500    -100   B   A  False
2   94000      50   C   D  False
3   18300     -50   D   C  False
4   94500     100   E   E   True
```

In words the logic is:
"For each element in ID1 (`apply`), check if there is at least (`any`) a row of the dataframe where ID2 = ID1 and Account = 94500"